# Spring Boot Many to Many Rest API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I am building a simple Rest API for a Notes App, I have two entities: Notes and Categories with a Many to Many relationship, but I am not able to join the categories when I try to get the Notes

The data is getting related in the database with the intermediate table

Note.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Note {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  private String title;
  private String content;
  private Boolean archived;
  private LocalDate lastModified = LocalDate.now();
  @ManyToMany(fetch = jakarta.persistence.FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
  @JoinTable(name = "note_categories", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "note_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
  Set<Category> categories;
}
```

VMNote.java

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class VMNote {
  private Long id;
  private String title;
  private String content;
  private Boolean archived;
  private LocalDate lastModified = LocalDate.now();
  Set<Category> categories;
}
```

NoteDTO.java

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class NoteDTO {
  private Long id;
  private String title;
  private String content;
  private Boolean archived;
  private LocalDate lastModified;
  private Set<Long> categoryIds;
  private Set<Category> categories;
}
```

Category.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Category {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories")
  Set<Note> notes;
}
```

NoteController.java

```
  @GetMapping
  public ResponseEntity<List<Note>> getAllNotes() {
    List<Note> notes = noteService.getAllNotes();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(notes, HttpStatus.OK);
  }

  @GetMapping("/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity<VMNote> getNoteById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    VMNote note = noteService.getNote(id);
    return note == null ? new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) : new ResponseEntity<>(note, HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

NoteService.java

```
  public List<Note> getAllNotes() {
    return noteRepository.findAll();
  }

  public VMNote getNote(Long id) {
    Note note = noteRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);

    if (note == null)
      return null;

    VMNote vmNote = new VMNote();
    vmNote.setId(note.getId());
    vmNote.setTitle(note.getTitle());
    vmNote.setContent(note.getContent());
    vmNote.setArchived(note.getArchived());
    vmNote.setLastModified(note.getLastModified());

    return vmNote;
  }

  public Note addNote(NoteDTO note) {
    Note newNote = new Note();
    newNote.setTitle(note.getTitle());
    newNote.setContent(note.getContent());
    newNote.setArchived(note.getArchived());
    newNote.setLastModified(note.getLastModified());

    if (note.getCategoryIds() == null)
      return noteRepository.save(newNote);

    Set<Category> categories = note.getCategoryIds().stream().map(category -> {
      Optional<Category> categoryOptional = categoryRepository.findById(category);
      return categoryOptional.orElse(null);
    }).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    newNote.setCategories(categories);

    return noteRepository.save(newNote);
  }
```

The controller and service for category are basically the same as the notes

I tried getting the category ids from the note but it just come empty besides they are stored in the database

Answer (score 0):

Just one doubt here,

```
 if (note.getCategoryIds() == null)
  return noteRepository.save(newNote);
```

If category is null, then you are saving the note?

Comment: More like: If the category IDs are null, then just save the Note without any category
If not, create a category for every category ID and store them in the new Note, then save the note